# What is the alternative for enumerate() for JavaScript Proxy to trap for ... in

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

What is the alternative for the [enumerate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/enumerate)()

for JavaScript Proxy to trap

> for ... in

Since enumerate() is deprecated.

Comment: What exactly is your use case? The [`ownKeys` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/ownKeys) should suffice

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45549376/1084004

Answer (score 0):

Negatives make for unsatsifying answers, but unfortunately, I don't believe there's any direct replacement. Although the `ownKeys` trap will be triggered by a `for-in` loop (because its [initialization](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-runtime-semantics-forin-div-ofheadevaluation-tdznames-expr-iterationkind) uses the abstract [`EnumerateObjectProperties`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-enumerate-object-properties) operation, which has to get the keys for an object via `[[OwnPropertyKeys]]`), `ownKeys` will also be triggered *other* times the keys of an object are required, not just when being used in a `for-in` loop.