# Javascript proxy a collection to single object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've never used Proxy before, but I think it should be possible to "merge" an collection of objects into a single object. 
It needs to remain "live" because the original fields will have value changes performed on them.

Ignore key collisions at this stage:

Given:

```
const fields = [{
  name: 'hello',
  value: 1
 },{
   name: 'goodbye',
   value : 2
 }];
```

Output:

```
const proxy = { hello:1 , goodbye :2 }
```

I definitely need to be able to iterate over the proxied object with a `for in`.

Have start a pen here, but haven't got very far: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mMRaKw?editors=1111

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like:

```js
const fields = [{name: 'hello',value: 1}, { name: 'goodbye', value: 2}];

let handler = {
  get: function(target, name) {
    if (name === 'flatten') {    
      return target.reduce((a, c) => {
        a[c.name] = c.value;
        return a
      }, {});
    } else {
      return target[name];
    }
  },
   set: function(target, prop, value) {
      let obj = target.find(o => o.name === prop);
      if(obj) {        
         obj.value = value;
         return true;
      }
      return false;
      
   }
};

let prox = new Proxy(fields, handler);

console.log('flat obj', JSON.stringify(prox.flatten))

// update original
fields[0].value=10;
// change reflected in proxy
console.log('flatten.hello',prox.flatten.hello);
// update proxy
prox.goodbye = 200;
// change reflected in original
console.log('original', fields[1].value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with the Proxy target as an empty object (if the Array is proxied, the `for in` will iterate numbered entries).

```js
const fields = [{name: 'hello',value: 1}, { name: 'goodbye', value: 2}];

let handler = {
  get: function(target, name) {
      var f = fields.find(f => f.name === name);
      return f && f.value;
  },
  ownKeys: function(target) {
      return fields.map(f => f.name);
  },
  getOwnPropertyDescriptor: function(target, prop) {
    return { configurable: true, enumerable: true };
  }
};

let prox = new Proxy({}, handler);

// update original
fields[0].value=10;
// change reflected in proxy
console.log('proxy.hello',prox.hello);

for( let i in prox ){
  console.log(i)
  console.log(prox[i])
}
console.log(prox)
```

Comment: `for(let i in prox){console.log(i,prox[i])}` ownKeys on proxy: trap result did not include length.

Comment: @Simon - maybe I've misunderstood what you want to achieve, I took the loop from your codepen. Length is an array property, if you want an array you won't have enumerable properties. If you update your question with the specifics, I'll update my answer